# Cakephp - login failure when the database column Is set to value other than 1

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication

I am currently working with cakephp and have a login form that works perfectly , I mean , it worked perfectly ...

My table of users is something like this :

```
id user email password plan_id active
```

When users have the plan_id = 1 perfeimtamente login works , but when the plan_id = 3 login is failing ...

My login settings are:

```
$this->Auth->authenticate = array(
   'Form' => array (
      'userModel ' => 'Supplier'
      'fields' = > array (
      'username ' => 'email' ,
      'password' => 'password '
   )
   ' scope ' => array (
     ' Supplier.active ' => 1
   )
);
```

I can not understand what's going on ...
The User and password are correct , when I change the value of the column plan_id I can not log in
If you can help me thank you now.

Answer (score 0):

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#recursive

Solved
with 'recursive' => -1

```
$this->Auth->authenticate = array(
   'Form' => array (
      'userModel ' => 'Supplier',
      'fields' = > array (
         'username ' => 'email' ,
         'password' => 'password ',
       ),
      'scope' => array (
         'Supplier.active ' => 1
       ),
      'recursive' => -1 
);
```

Comment: Your description of the problem and the solution don't match/make sense. All recursive does is prevent returning joined model data - it's not going to directly make the difference between being able to login or not.

Comment: @AD7six I agree that it makes no sense , but I decided so... 
I wanted to understand why not authenticated , if anyone can answer ...